# emulator in commandline do not have always the property "dev.bootcomplete"

Tags: android, android-emulator, continuous-integration, adb

I'm using the emulator by command-line for our continuous integration server for our android application. With that approach we can test all Android Versions automatically. For the automatic installation and testing we are using the property "dev.bootcomplete", which is provided by the android emulator. Unfortunately we don't get it always. After a newly created emulator we are retrieving it, but when the emulator is several times used it do'nt throw it again... 
Has Anybody an idea?

Commands/ results:

[user@mob_ci ~]$ adb shell getprop dev.bootcomplete

error: device offline

[user@mob_ci ~]$ adb shell getprop dev.bootcomplete

1

Comment: What CI Server are you using? Do you use a plugin for that ? Do you have your on script?

Comment: we are using teamcity with the maven android plugin. :)

Comment: hmm so that is the only output you get? Does after a fail the next build work or do you have to do something like adb kill-server and the adb restart ? I use the hudson ci server and the android gradle plugin, if i watch the console there is also this command: adb -s emulatorname shell connect localhost:Port , does the maven plugin start the emulator or do you start it by script?

Comment: no it is not the script. I did by hand, what you see above. I must kill the emulator by hand... so the next build can be run, without any problems. The emulator start is done by the maven plugin.

Comment: Are you testing on 3.0+ emulators? if so try restarting the adb. according to this link http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/ api level 11+ will often detach from the emulator during the launch process.

Comment: also you said "dev.bootcomplete" when that link says "dev.bootcompleted", which works fairly consistently for me

Answer (score 2):

I use hudson as a ci server, for hudson there is a android plugin which manages the emulator, it even creates the emulator for you if you want.

I would either check if "error: device offline" happens and then run

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

or

shutdown the emulator after each build, as it's not necessary that the emulator runs all the time or do the tests run all the time ?

hope this helps :)